# Using getopts with a switchless path

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a short script, utilizing `getopts`. I want it to take optional switches, or just run as the default. I have a `-d` switch to enable debugging, and I'd like every other argument to be a path. The ideal command line looks as such, with paths being optional, and theoretically limitless:

`$0 [-d] [/path1[ /path2[ ...]]]`

I am currently using `getopts` as such below:

```
while getopts ":d" opt; do
    case $opt in
        d)
            DEBUG=true
            ;;
        h)
            echo USAGE: $0 \[-d\] \[\/mount\/point\/1 ...\]
            exit 0
            ;;
        \?)
            echo Incorrect syntax
            ;;
    esac
done
```

What can I put in the `while getopts` section, and in the `case` set, to allow paths to be entered, as many as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need anything in the loop or `getopts` call for that. `getopts` stops at the first non-option.

After your loop all your paths will still be in positional arguments available for use.

Also you don't have `h` in your `getopts` string so it isn't valid.

Comment: So I can cycle through them with a standard loop... Will the `getopts` also remove the switches, so I can keep using `$@`?

Comment: No, `getopts` does not remove the switches but it does set `OPTIND` to the first non-option argument. So a loop over `${@:$OPTIND}` will work and/or `shift $((OPTIND - 1))` will shift them away.